# Reboot Android (x86) from the command line

Tags: android, android-x86

Is there a command line command to reboot Android safely? My GUI does not work and I want to do a restart after some changes to make it work and I guess a normal reboot is better than a forced restart.

I could not find any other guide regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
adb shell svc power reboot
```